# Why don't wallets auto-create an associated token account if one doesn't exist?

Tags: wallet, fungible-token, phantom, solflare, associated-token-account

I have a fake USDC coin that I created on testnet.
I minted 100 FUSDC to a token account belonging to Wallet 1.
Then tried to send it from Wallet 1 -> Wallet 2 which also reside in my Phantom wallet.

It said there was an error while trying to send tokens to Wallet 2.
I think it's because I never created an ATA for FUSDC on Wallet 2.

But isn't that the whole point of an ATA - so that the sender doesn't have to worry whether the recipient has a token account for a particular coin or not?

Why doesn't the wallet just auto-create an ATA for the recipient?

Update: I was using Phantom wallet.

Comment: please cite the wallet displaying this behavior

Comment: this sounds like an issue that should be reported to phantom support.  either they have a bug or are not raising sufficient information to the user such that they can resolve the situation on their own

Comment: I tried to lookup the support channels on their website but I could only find a help page with FAQs and a chatbot that doesn't have an option to chat with a human.

Comment: @trent.sol I found a similar issue with sollet.io as well, except this time I got the logs: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/359/which-program-is-this-4mnpdku9wfmveezbmt3eipfs5ovvwtjb31pexdjaaxx5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phantom and Sollet are calling the assert-owner program by Serum before creating an ATA.

This program is only deployed on mainnet. It is not available on testnet/devnet.

This is why we can't send tokens to a wallet without ATA on devnet/testnet.

More info: [Which program is this: 4MNPdKu9wFMvEeZBMt3Eipfs5ovVWTJb31pEXDJAAxX5?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/359/which-program-is-this-4mnpdku9wfmveezbmt3eipfs5ovvwtjb31pexdjaaxx5)

Answer (score 2):

creating a token account costs sol, so if you want your transaction to create an account and pay for it you need to specify --allow-unfunded-recipient in your transaction.

Comment: Does any GUI wallet have an equivalent option? Like Solflare/Phantom?

Comment: If you check the transaction in solscan you should see a call to Create Associated Account. Maybe your wallet does not have enough sol to pay for that? Phantom token transfer has --allow-unfunded-recipient as default i think.

Comment: My wallet has 1 SOL. Does solscan show failed transactions as well?

Comment: Yes if there is a programm error you can see it on solscan as a failed transaction. If you are on devnet you may need to switch solscan to devnet as well.