# What is Owner Validation Program?

Tags: program, spl, associated-token-account

I was reading the source code of sollet.io.

Whenever they are creating an ATA, they are also calling some instruction of the Owner Validation Program: https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet/blob/0c7da6e4429959419d129ec8b7ccf7387222e5a3/src/utils/tokens/instructions.js#L187-L194

I couldn't find a reference to this program anywhere in the Solana docs.

Does anyone know what this program does and what are its instructions?

Comment: @trent.sol Yes, it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a deployment of the [Serum assert-owner program](https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex/blob/master/assert-owner/program-id.md).

Ref: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/363/234